# the square of mean of two numbers is always greater than their product

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just wondering about how to prove the above theorem but I was exhausted. I have searched across the internet but was unable to find suitable prove of this.
once again I write the theorem
"the square of mean of two numbers is always greater than their products".

Comment: This is the [arithmetic mean - geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) (squared)

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$$( \frac{a+b}{2})^2 \ge ab \iff \frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4} \ge ab \iff a^2-2ab+b^2 \ge 0 \iff (a-b)^2 \ge 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(x+y)^2-4xy=(x-y)^2\ge0$. Can you see how to rearrange to get $\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2\ge xy$?

Comment: Oh thanks I haven't thought of using  this identity  to prove it.